# Use LocalStorage with Checkbox Checked by Default

Tags: javascript

**Pen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWaJaP?editors=0010
**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/qnLhtzss/

By default I want the checkbox checked, but if the user changes it I want it saved to what the user saved it as.

It saves the state when the user clicks on the link but by default the checkbox is not checked when it's suppose to be.

Can someone explain why this is not working?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="changePrev" checked>
<label for="changePrev">Auto Update Preview</label>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Toggle Auto Update Preview
var checkedPrev = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("autoUpdate"));
var changePrev = document.getElementById("changePrev");
changePrev.checked = checkedPrev;

$("#changePrev").on("change", function() {
  (this.checked) ? localStorage.setItem("autoUpdate", "true") : localStorage.setItem("autoUpdate", "false");
}).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the first time the use navigates to the page

`var checkedPrev = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("autoUpdate"));`

will be `null` because there is no `"autoUpdate"` key present in the LocalStorage. This subsequently sets `changePrev.checked = checkedPrev` to `null`, and ultimately results in the checkbox becoming unchecked.

You can fix this by a simple `null` check on `checkedPrev` and defaulting to `true` if it was `null`.

```
// Toggle Auto Update Preview
var checkedPrev = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("autoUpdate"));
// If checkedPrev === null then the use has never been here before.
// Make checkedPrev default to true
checkedPrev = checkedPrev === null ? true : false;
var changePrev = document.getElementById("changePrev");
changePrev.checked = checkedPrev;

$("#changePrev").on("change", function() {
  (this.checked) ? localStorage.setItem("autoUpdate", "true") : localStorage.setItem("autoUpdate", "false");
}).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Now I understand what I was doing wrong. Thank you :)